# JavaScript suppress a specific error

Tags: javascript, console.log

I have the following line in my JavaScript file, which creates an error message on the console:

```
myObject.width = 315;
```

I want to hide this error message on the console. I mean that, this line of code will run, it will give error, but won't display it on the console log.

I read about `window.onerror`, but it did not work. As I understand, this disables all the errors on a page, however I want to disable the errors of only my line. I tried putting it right after, but it didn't work either:

```
myObject.width = 315;
window.onerror = function(){
       return true;
    }
```

Is there any workaround for this? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want it to give an error if it's not going to show the error anywhere? Why not just check if `myObject` is set?

Comment: I don't want to give the error. I just want to run the code with it's errors, but not show them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking this shouldn't need to yield an error. What's the error you're getting? That myObject isn't defined? If so, just add a safeguard and check if it's defined. Such as:

```
if (myObject) {
    myObject.width = 315
}
```

That said, you can surpress it by wrapping it in a [try-catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

```
try {
    myObject.width = 315;
}
catch(err) {
    // do nothing
}
```

To see what's happening, try running the following code and see what's happening when you're removing the `var myObject = {}` line.

```
var myObject = {}

try {
    myObject.width = 315;
} catch(err) {
    console.log('error');
}

console.log(myObject)
```

Comment: This prevents the error, but the line of code does not run eventually.

Comment: @FarukYazıcı What do you expect it to do if there's an error?

Comment: @FarukYazıcı The line myObject.width = 315; is very much executed. I updated my answer with an example. See that it logs the updated object? And if you're removing the first var statement - it'll log "error".